# Unable to update Intel HD graphics driver

Tags: intel-graphics

I tried using the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux to update my Intel HD graphics driver but everytime the following message shows up:

```
W:https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main/dists/wily/InRelease: Signature by key 6C82391DC41365FB56EC3CE4A496EB03894A3A8D uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), 
W:http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), 
W:http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), 
W:http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/InRelease: Signature by key 165D673674A995B3E64BF0CF4F191A5A8844C542 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1), 
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-wv/pulseaudio-equalizer-ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the Warnings (W) but you have to remove the ppa with errors (E), because they are not available to Xenial.

In order to do so, you can either manually remove the `.list` files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or (preferred) via the GUI program "Software and Updates" (you can find it in the Dash).

Please note that the Intel graphic drivers that you can take from that repository do not yet support 16.04.

Comment: Hey! I'm quite new to Linux. It would be very helpful if you could be more precise. Do I just untick pulseaudio in "Software and Updates"? Or, if done manually, how should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: In principle yes, that's sufficient. But it is actually better if you then remove them (there is a Remove button that you can click when you select one of them), so they will leave no trace on your pc.

Comment: Thanks! But, I actually wanted to update the Intel driver as my screen resolution on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS isn't correct. I've tried going to the System Settings -> Display -> Resolution and set it to 1366 x 768 (16:9) [which is the highest available], but that doesn't help.

Comment: As I said before, this has nothing to do with the error you reported, and you should ask Intel to support 16.04 with their latest driver, since it is something that nobody else can control :)

Comment: I see. I also have an AMD Radeon R5 M230 chip in my laptop. I read somewhere that Ubuntu has dropped support for AMD drivers in 16.04, but that open source AMD drivers can be installed. Could you guide me how to do that, or maybe post a link which I can refer to? This wasn't very helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: AMD has dropped supporto for Linux, not the other way around (and any Linux, not just Ubuntu). The Open drivers are already installed by default, no need to do anything (unless you removed them, but why would you?)

Comment: How do I check that the AMD drivers are installed on my system? When I do this: lspci -nn | grep VGA, it shows this: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
. Basically, I want to improve my screen resolution. It's bugging me a lot.

Comment: I cannot help on that, I do not use amd since they have a very bad support for Linux users. it's better to open a new specific question, although I think that people will just suggest that you install an older version of Linux ( Ubuntu or other distribution).

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks for answering my questions though.